# Scrolling with mouse wheel inside screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I use `screen` with a simple status line. If I what to scroll, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+a <kbd>ESC</kbd> to enter the copy mode and then I can scroll using the keyboard. This works great also with multiple buffers and splits.

My question is: **How can I configure screen to use the mouse wheel to scroll?**

*Note 1: Using the mouse wheel I can scroll inside my terminal, but this doesn't work with multiple buffers and splits at all.*

*Note 2: The* `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@` *solution doesn't help, since it uses the terminal scrolling. This is not compatible with status line, multiple buffers and splits.*

The best solution IMHO would be:

- In copy mode mouse wheel used for scrolling, like keyboard arrays do.
- If screen in the normal mode and the mouse wheel event "scroll up" comes in, screen switches to the copy mode and processes the event
- If screen in the copy mode and the mouse wheel event "scroll down" comes in, that hits the bottom, screen leaves the copy mode
- Screen status line is always visible and get refreshed (works already, if scrolling with keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen` does not ***know*** about the wheel-mouse.  It only knows about keys (including escape-sequences) sent by the terminal and its keyboard:

- `screen` knows about **mouse-clicks** (its source-code mentions only "left mouse-click").  You can read the source-code ([display.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/display.c)) to see that it does no more than that ([this, in particular](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/display.c#n2548), is the only place where `screen` decodes mouse-events).
- The xterm mouse-protocol will send buttons 4 and 5 to indicate the wheel-mouse.  `screen` knows nothing about this; applications running in the terminal may handle it specially.
- Some terminals will send cursor-keys to imitate up/down scrolling when in the alternate-screen.  `screen` (as expected) passes this on to the application as well.